# Aggregate assignment to access type is not static?

Tags: vhdl

I have the following code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity static_test is
end entity;

architecture sim of static_test is
  type rec_t is record
    sl  : std_logic;
    slv : std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
  end record;

  type rec_ptr_t is access rec_t;
begin

  process
    variable ptr  : rec_ptr_t;
  begin
    ptr   := new rec_t;

    (ptr.sl, ptr.slv) := std_logic_vector'(x"00");
    wait;
  end process;

end architecture sim;
```

And I get the following errors from ActiveHDL:

> Error: COMP96_0309: static_test.vhd : (28, 6): Expression in element association of the aggregate must be a locally static name that denotes a variable.
>
> Error: COMP96_0309: static_test.vhd : (28, 14): Expression in element association of the aggregate must be a locally static name that denotes a variable.

I cannot find the LRM section that specifies an aggregate assignment needs to be locally static, and I also dont understand why `ptr.sl` or `ptr.slv` is not considered locally static. The lengths are known in the type. Is it just that an access type cannot ever be considered locally static (it kind of makes sense to me).

Comment: So, I guess it would be fine to assign each member of the record in turn? (I suppose you don't need to dereference using `ptr.all` because `ptr` points to a record?). And the aggregate assignment would work fine if `ptr` were a `rec_t`, not an access type. It seems like working + working = broken.

Comment: Individually works fine.  Its the aggregate that needs to be static (though I can't find the relevant lrm entry)

Comment: The aggregate with the errors is on the LHS of the assignment. IEEE Std 1076-1993 7.3 Static expressions "Certain forms of expression can be evaluated during the analysis of the design unit in which they appear; such an expression is said to be *locally static*." The prefix `ptr` can't be evaluated (read) at analysis time, it's an access time whose value is assigned at run time. During analysis it's value is `null`. 8.5 Variable assignment statement "Furthermore, the expression in each element association of the aggregate must be a locally static name that denotes a variable."

Comment: For -2008 that's 9.4 Static expressions, 9.4.1 General and 10.6.2 Simple variable assignments, 10.6.2.1 General, and yes a subtype constraint can be provided by an allocator (9.3.7 Allocators).

Comment: `ptr.all := rec_t'( '0', others => (others => '0'));`